# How to get a checkbox from ListViewItem in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView that contains more than ListViewItem
each ListViewItem contains a checkBox:

```
<ListViewItem>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}" Name="myCheckBx1">
            <StackPanel  Margin="10,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="Airline"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </CheckBox>
    </ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}" Name="myCheckBx2">
            <StackPanel  Margin="10,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="Fleet"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </CheckBox>
    </ListViewItem>
```

Now on C# i want to get all the checkBoxes in my ListView, how can i do this? 
i want to do something as the following:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView) {
    // Get the checkBox here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why you want to have all Checkboxes.?

Comment: Yes, want to get all the checkboxes in my ListView

Comment: I think i asked for Why ?

Comment: To get and count the checked checkboxes!

Comment: Yes i use MVVM while creating a custom ListView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use LogicalTreeHelper if there is no other way:

```
<ListView x:Name="list"> ... </ListView>
```

In code-behind:

```
var ref = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(list);
```

It returns IEnumerable. I think by executing this code, you'll get the IEnumerable which contains ListViewItems element. So, for each element from this collection, use the same pattern:

```
var ref = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(list);
```

And you'll get the Checkbox object. Then you can get every Property you want from your Checkbox.

Example:

```
foreach (object listView in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(list as FrameworkElement))
{
    foreach (object checkbox in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj as FrameworkElement))
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing, but i got an error while executing, 
     foreach (object list in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(listView as FrameworkElement))
            {
                foreach (object checkbox in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(list as FrameworkElement))
                {
                    CheckBox c = checkbox as CheckBox;
                    c.IsChecked = true;
                }
            } 
i tried to check every checkbox for example and got XamlParseException with message: Cannot create instance of listView

Comment: So you have a problem in XamlCode. When you get the XamlParseException you always get the code line and code column. Check your xaml code and look for error. I double checked this solution, I copied your xaml code and paste it (ofcourse ListViewItem's must be childrem of ListView, so I added it to your xaml code). Please paste some code if problems will occure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListViewItem.Content property

Comment: How to use it? i tried to do: foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items) var v = item.Content as CheckBox; but v get always null value!

Answer (score 0):

Make all your checkboxes with same id(bcoz those are in different listitem). Use the following code

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView) {
  CheckBox chk=item.FindControl("checkboxid");
}
```

Comment: Can't Find the FindControl() method on ListViewItem ?